# how to use selenium for desktop application?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, regression-testing

I am working on a retail software where i have to do automation testing of desktop application using selenium. How it can be done using selenium? And we have portal too in which some details are being updated. So the testing will be done for a desktop application and web application. i am fresher i this field and started learning new things. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance. i have completed automation of portal but there are details which are being updated to portal from software.

Comment: what is the desktop app made with?

Comment: desktop application is made of delphi programming language. u have asked for that right???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium only works in a browser environment.
 
You could try out [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Selenium can do it. This software is tailored for web applications and it only runs in browsers. I've recently heard a lot about AutoIt, which is more appropriate for desktop applications.
Fortunately, there seem to exist ways to make Selenium and AutoIt work together. http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/

Good luck with your issue